# My brakes locked up or got hard to press

Tags: ford, brakes, f-150

I have a 1996 ford f150 and was driving normally saw a red light coming so I barely tapped my brake to slow down but it acted like if I had hit the brakes very hard and I slid after that it was fine later that day I had went to a restaurant and was backing out to leave then I went into drive went forward to leave and it did the same thing I barely tap the brake and it locked up or something and this was a rainy day I don’t know how much this would effect my brakes but thought I should mention this

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!